# Putting Labels Inside Nodes in R ggraph package

Tags: r, label, nodes, ggraph

I am trying to visualize a network using ggraph. My code is as follows:

```
ggraph(x, layout = "fr") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(width = weight), alpha = 0.50, edge_color = "grey20") +
  geom_node_point(color = "black", size = 12, show.legend = FALSE, family = "serif") +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name),  
                  repel = TRUE, show.legend = FALSE, family = "serif") +
  theme_graph(background = "white")
```

It results in the following snippet of network plot:

[Node Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQsAe.png)

Is it possible to create labels inside the nodes in ggraph? I tried geom_node_label and geom_node_text but none of them works that way. I also upload an example of what I have in mind below:

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iITzk.png)

I would really appreciate your help. I wish everyone a healthy summer.

Answer (score 1):

`geom_node_text()` is correct. the text was hidden as it was black on black.

```
x <- data.frame('from' = c(1,2,3,4), 'to' = c(3,3,1,1), 'weight' = c(1,1,1,1))

ggraph(x, layout = "fr") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(width = weight), alpha = 0.50, edge_color = "grey20") +
  geom_node_point(color = "black", size = 12, show.legend = FALSE, family = "serif") +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name),  colour = 'white', size=10,
                  show.legend = FALSE, family = "serif") +
  theme_graph(background = "white")
```

gives this plot

[image]

Comment: Is this out of date? I'm really struggling. Running your example gives me the error `Ignoring unknown parameters: family`. If I delete the references to `family`, I get the same error I'm running into, where `aes()` doesn't seem to pull in the dataframe column. In your example, I get `object 'name' not found` (and I wondered what that refers to); if I replace it with `weight`, which is in the df, I get `object 'weight' not found`.

Comment: Running the code in my example works still fine for me; although I also get the warning about family (despite being mentioned as an understood aes in help). `name` is generated internally, you can run `ggraph::create_layout(x, 'fr')` to see what happens to `x` for graph creation.